# Is it possible to "pause" a message from being sent to check it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

What I mean by this is, I want to make a moderation bot, but something that'd be cool is to pause a messaging being sent while the bot checks it, and then approve it to be sent. The reason I'd like to do this is so any inappropriate content cannot be seen at all, but if I didn't do this then people could see the bad content for a second or two before the bot edits or deletes it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad as written, and may draw negative feedback as a result.  Aside from the fact that you really just asked a yes/no question (but probably wanted to ask how),  there are too many possible ways that something like this could be done to answer in this format.  It is better to show what you have attempted so far and ask about the challenges you are having with your real code.  see [ask].

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the response. The point is, I don't know where to even start with this and wanted to know if and how this can be done.

Comment: Being that this is a QA site and not a tutorial site, it's hard to offer a "this is how you start" kind of answer;  as to if this can be done, the more experienced you get in programming the more you realize that the answer to that is rarely ever no.

Comment: I was mainly wondering if the Discord bot API allows for it.

Comment: Yes, of course it does, there are at least 3 or 4 ways to do this.  you could listen for the send event or listen for the raw stream events, as examples.  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message.

Comment: Sorry for late response. That's not what I want. I want to set "middleware" of sorts so that the bot can check the message before it shows for other users.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I understood what you want to do. Unfortunately, this can't be done: the bot is considered by Discord as a user, and receives the messages in the same way users do. It's not possible to "approve" o "reject" message, you can only moderate them after they've been sent :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the bot interrupts the message before it's sent to other users that is impossible. Bots are unable to intercept the message before it reaches other users as the bot is considered a user when it comes to messaging receiving. It receives the message the same time the user does.